# ExtJs component cleanup

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I read the following comment in ExtJs-in-action -

```
'Do not dismiss the destruction portion of a Component’s lifecycle if you plan on developing your own custom
Components. Many developers have gotten into trouble when they’ve ignored this crucial step and have code that
has left artifacts such as data Stores that continuously poll web servers...'
```

I have never called explicit destructors/destroy on my my containers/components in 3.4.x
Though things seem to work fine - I am curious on 
1. What are some instances where implementing destructors becomes essential
2.what is the proper convention to handle component destruction on close of browser instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [guide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/core_concepts/memory_management.html) may be a good read.

You should always consider cleaning up your objects after they are needed to free up memory, especially unbinding event listeners and any timers you've created with `setInterval`. Once the object reference is destroyed you cannot access it but it could still be listening to or firing events and using up resources.

Generally in ExtJs, You free up resources in the destroy method, but just remember to call the `callParent()` function too so that ExtJs does it's own cleanup.

Here is another [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jsmemory/) from IBM in 2012 that seems to go into more depth on the subject.